# How to create a 2-dimensional unboxed array from a list of 1-dimensional ones?

Tags: arrays, haskell, repa

Repa has [`fromListUnboxed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.0.2/docs/Data-Array-Repa-Repr-Unboxed.html#v:fromListUnboxed) that allows to create a 1-dimensional array from a list of values. But how can I create a 2-dimensional one given a list of 1-dimensional unboxed ones (of equal lengths)?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `reshape` function: `reshape :: (Shape sh1, Shape sh2, Source r1 e) => sh2 -> Array r1 sh1 e -> Array D sh2 e`.
It's compile-time only (no runtime overhead).

Comment: But you'd first have to concat the arrays, wouldn't you? That incurs a runtime cost and also the question of how to treat the lengths.

Comment: An Unboxed array is kept in a memory chunk, so you have to reserve the chunk to fill it with data. If you've got a group of such chunks (the 1D's arrays) then you have to copy the memory into new, bigger chunk - no matter if you're using Haskell, C++ or any other high-performance language here. If you want to create a 2D array from a list of 1D's you have to copy all the data from those 1D's into a new reserved chunk of memory.  What do you mean by "how to treat the lengths"?

Comment: He may be referring to the fact that arrays are not indexed by size.

Comment: Sounds good. Is there a built-in way how to concatenate a collection of arrays (of equal lengths)?

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this problem. I resolved it by converting the list of
arrays to unboxed vectors, concatenating those, and converting them back to a
repa array. Very clumsy, but that's all I could think about.

```
import           Data.Array.Repa     as R
import           Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import           Prelude             as P

arrs = P.replicate 5 $ fromListUnboxed (ix1 10) [0..9 :: Int]

main = print concatenatedArrs
  where vectors = P.map toUnboxed arrs
        concatenatedVectors = V.concat vectors
        concatenatedArrs = fromUnboxed (R.ix2 5 10) concatenatedVectors
```